# PHP how to display multiple array values

Tags: php, mysql

How can I display array values that I retrieved from the database for example the following array values.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $post_id[] = $row['id'];
    $post_user_id[] = $row['user_id'];
    $post_title[] = $row['title'];
}
```

Output.

```
<li><a href="' . $post_user_id . 'post.php?id="' . $post_id . '">' . $post_title . '</a></li>
<li><a href="' . $post_user_id . 'post.php?id="' . $post_id . '">' . $post_title . '</a></li>
<li><a href="' . $post_user_id . 'post.php?id="' . $post_id . '">' . $post_title . '</a></li>
<li><a href="' . $post_user_id . 'post.php?id="' . $post_id . '">' . $post_title . '</a></li>
<li><a href="' . $post_user_id . 'post.php?id="' . $post_id . '">' . $post_title . '</a></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following outside the `while` loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($post_id);$i++) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$post_user_id[$i].'post.php?id='.$post_id[$i].'">'.$post_title[$i] . '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: All your lines will be the same. Where $i?

Comment: sizeof() more faster than count()

Comment: Check this with firebug. Or you can read about operations speed on http://phpbench.com/

Comment: @Alexander honestly, this site makes people totally misunderstood  performance issues. It makes people think that difference between count() and sizeof() (if it really was, between just **different names of single function**) does matter anything. While it doesn't. And you are right with firebug. Just always test everything with firebug. When network latency involved, nothing of such a microoptimization could be noticeable. Trust me, no code itself does affect performance. Data manipulation does affect it.

Comment: @Alexander Shrapnel is right, but to put it in less aggressive terms: [`sizeof`: Description: "This function is an alias of: `count()`."](http://php.net/sizeof) Please provide irrefutable proof that an alias of a function is faster than the function itself. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  $data[] = $row;
}
?>
```

Output.

```
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
<li>
 <a href="<?=$row['post_user_id']?>post.php?id=<?=$row['post_id']?>">
  <?=$row['post_title']?>
 </a>
</li>
<? endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $post_id = $row['id'];
    $post_user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $post_title = $row['title'];
    echo "<li><a href=\"" . $post_user_id . "post.php?id=" . $post_id . "\">" . $post_title . "</a></li>";
}
```

But in my Oppinion, the Links are not very well formated, you would need a [userid]post.php for each user. Better would be:

```
    echo "<li><a href=\""post.php?userid=\"".$post_user_id."\"&id=". $post_id ."\">" . $post_title . "</a></li>";
```

So your post.php gets the userid and the id per GET by clicking on the link.

Comment: I dont want to use it in the same while loop.

Comment: $post_id[] is array. $post_id - is not array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($post_id); $i++) {
   echo '<li><a href="' . $post_user_id[$i] . 'post.php?id=' . $post_id[$i] . '">' 
   . $post_title[$i] . '</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting up a database record (a row) across multiple variables, it's usually a better idea to keep them together in a multi-dimensional array like this:

```
$posts = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $posts[] = $row;
}

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post['id'];
    echo $post['user_id'];
    echo $post['title'];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way would be

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   echo '<li><a href="' . $row['user_id'] . 'post.php?id="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a></li>';
}
```

if you need the same output. But in my opinion the links are not well formed.